# How to listen to ISM bands?

Tags: internet-radio

I need for my job to use ISM Radio protocol, 868Mhz in Europe where I live. The material are an antenna which connects through USB to my computer.

What software can I use for listening to this specific radio band with the antenna?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using RTL-SDR? In other words what hardware receiver do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gqrx](http://gqrx.dk/) is quite good for listening to Software Defined Radio receivers. It is [available in the Ubuntu universe repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=gqrx-sdr), or you can [install from their Personal Package Archive](http://gqrx.dk/download/install-ubuntu).

If you need to decode a more complicated protocol, then you may need to use [GNU Radio](https://www.gnuradio.org/).

Comment: I finally had to use [GNU Radio](https://www.gnuradio.org/) cause [Gqrx](http://gqrx.dk/) was somehow too simple for my usage. Thanks a lot